# Speech to text with nerd-dictation is slower than expected

Tags: performance, speech-recognition

I have recently discovered the amazing nerd-dictation (https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation) software, allowing speech-to-text in Linux. Install is easy, and many languages are supported. For now, it works only under X11 session, no Wayland.

I did a few tests, and speech-recognition was really good (even using the small model), however, it takes too much time to process my sentences, and during this time the computer completely freezes. I do not understand why this happens, as it is supposed to be able to run on a Raspberry. My computer is decent, so I should not be having this problem.

How can I make this software work more efficiently?

Here is my config:

Intel Core I5-3570k @3,40 GHz
8 GiO Ram
Nvidia GeForce GT1030 graphic card
Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with xdotool, see https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation/issues/51.

I had the same issue and it got fixed when I switched to ydotool.
You don't need Wayland for ydotool, it also supports X11.

See https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation/blob/master/readme-ydotool.rst for instructions on how to use ydotool with nerd-dictation.